# why the select sql sometimes needs to add db.table in oracle

Tags: oracle, select

I have a problem with oracle, it confuses me.

My sql segment: "select * from table". It worked in navicat, but it didn't work in mybatis,table or view not find. I need to use this sql: "select * from db.table".

It happens too, when I create  database link.

The db config and user info are all same.

Comment: here is a useful article to solve your issue. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42955/query-without-having-to-specify-tables-schema